# Google search css issues

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, google-custom-search

I am new to CSE and created a new search engine for my website.  However, when I place the code on my website, it doesn't show properly.  Please refer to the below screenshot.

[image]

I have also added CSS Source file to my project and page.  Please advise what could be the reason.

This is the Code I got when I click Get Code in CSE

```
    <script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '011144611979136638912:ebxerpcbbsu';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Comment: It is hard to tell or analyze anything if you don't provide a piece of code. In order to improve your chances on getting your question solved you should add more information and provide some code you're using

Comment: I have added the code I got from Google CSE. Not sure why it behaves so

Comment: Let me guess - that looks like Bootstrap. http://box.galeksic.com/code/cse-and-bootstrap/